# Where does the snapshot command take its pixel samples from?

Tags: qgis, pixel

I'm using the snapshot command in QGIS with a horizontal extent from 0 units to 24 units to create an image with a horizontal resolution of 4 pixels. Are the output pixels located at 3,9,15,21 (seamless tiling) or at 0,8,16,24 (overlapping)?

Edit: Tried to do some tests on this in 2.14.3 Essen and wow, snapshot is so broken. See for yourself...

512x256 has a white 2-pixel bar on the right border:

[image: 512x256]

256x128 has the same problem, also 2 pixels wide:

[image: 256x128]

128x64 has the same problem, also 2 pixels wide:

[image: 128x64]

64x32 has the same problem, still 2 pixels wide:

[image: 64x32]

32x16 is all black:

[image: 32x16]

16x8 is all white:

[image: 16x8]

8x4 is all white:

[image: 8x4]

4x2 is all black again:

[image: 4x2]

Seriously, what is going on here?

Comment: This would be more suitable for a bug report. https://www.qgis.org/en/site/getinvolved/development/bugreporting.html#bugs-features-and-issues

Comment: True and I will submit a ticket, but my original question still stands and the bug is related to it.